# Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/removeAndDo' only in WebStorm

Tags: angular, webpack, webstorm

Attempting to shift from VS Code to WebStorm to work with an existing Angular project, however when running `ng serve` I receive the error:

```
Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/removeAndDo'
```

I have not shifted any files in any folders and I have manually added in both the the webpack libraries and `node_modules` in the project settings in WebStorm.

This issue does not occur in VS Code. Any help appreciated.

Comment: this is a runtime error, code is run by `ng serve`; the issue has nothing to do with the IDE being used.

Comment: Hi Lena, yes I'm aware that it is a run time error. However, the error only occurs when running ng-serve from the terminal within web storm, so I figured it may be a Web Storm configuration issue. I encounter no such error when serving from CMD, Powershell or the VS Code terminal.

Comment: there are 2 (possible) differences between the built-in and external terminals: 1. environment variables (though they are normally the same) 2. `node_modules/.bin` added to `%PATH%`. Try comparing `%PATH%` in the built-in and external terminals. And make sure that the folder you run `ng serve` in is the same in all cases

Answer (score 1):

`webpack/lib/removeAndDo` This package has been ***deprecated***

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin
>
> This package
>
> has been deprecated Author message:
>
> Deprecated. Please use
>   https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin

use this library instead of that

```
npm install --save-dev mini-css-extract-plugin
```

Comment: I will try this shortly :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

My node version was `10.15.1`.

Updating it to `14.17.3` solve the problem for me

P.S. I'm using **nvm**